# Why $K_5$ and $K_{3,3}$?

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, planar-graphs

Most people will have already guessed that this is about [Kuratowski's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kuratowski%27s_theorem).

The theorem states that every non-planar graph must contain a complete graph $K_5$ with five vertices or a complete bipartite graph $K_{3,3}$ with three vertices at each side - or subdivisions of these graphs.

I have seen a few proofs of this theorem (but not searched very much), but so far I have not found an explanation why exactly these two graphs occur in the theorem. What makes them so special?

Of course, $K_5$ is the smallest non-planar graph at all, but then, which role plays $K_{3,3}$ in the theorem?

Another approach, which I have tried a bit, was to search for properties that a minimal non-planar graph must have. In such a graph, no edge or vertex can be removed without making the graph non-planar, and no two edges which meet at a vertex of degree 2 can be unified. But this lead to no results, at least not for me.

So why do $K_5$ and $K_{3,3}$ occur in Kuratowski's theorem?

Comment: They are minor-minimal non-planar graph (any proper minor of any of them is planar). Any other non-planar graph is not minor-minimal, since it contains $K_5$ or $K_{33}$ as a minor.

Comment: Once you recognize that the property of planarity is closed under graph minors, the [Robertson-Seymour therorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robertson%E2%80%93Seymour_theorem) guarantees you that there's _some_ finite set of graphs such that any non-planar graph must contain (a subdivision of) one of them.

Comment: https://www.google.com/books/edition/Topological_Graph_Theory/6HmA_x0dL9oC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=topological+graph+theory&pg=PP1&printsec=frontcover

Comment: @WillJagy, presumably the book ([Gross and Tucker - Topological graph theory](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Topological_Graph_Theory/6HmA_x0dL9oC)) you [reference](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/385588/why-k-5-and-k-3-3#comment982569_385588) proves the planarity theorem, but did you mean to link to anything more specific in the book?

Comment: @LSpice. Not really. It appears the person asking has no knowledge of the area. The book can repair that.

Comment: $K_{3,3}$ is the smallest nonplanar graph if you're counting by the number of *edges*.

Comment: I think that rather than the number of edges, what's important about $K_{3,3}$ is that it is the *smallest* graph with all faces being of size at least 4.

Comment: @domotorp: in what sense does $K_{3,3}$ have faces? It is non-planar...

Comment: @lambda This is an interesting observation. If someone could write a proof of Kuratowski's theorem based on this fact, I would count it as "explanation" of $K_5$ and $K_{3,3}$. But I don't think it is easy.

Comment: @SamHopkins 4 is the minimal number of edges that the faces of the non-planar graph $K_{3,3}$ would have if it had a planar embedding. I hope this makes it clearer...

Comment: @rimu I was responding to this bit of your post: "Of course, $K_5$ is the smallest non-planar graph at all, but then, which role plays $K_{3,3}$ in the theorem?" I agree however that the observation that both graphs can be considered the "smallest" doesn't really explain anything.

Answer (score 8):

I have now found a paper by [A. Skopenkov](https://arxiv.org/abs/0802.3820) where he proves the theorem from the fact that $K_5$ and $K_{3,3}$ are the only graphs $G$ with the property

*For each edge $x y$, the Graph $G - x - y$ does not contain a [$\theta$-graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_graph_theory#T) and has no vertex of degree 1.*

where $G - x - y$ is the graph $G$ with the vertices $x$ and $y$ removed. This is at least a starting point for finding what makes $K_5$ and $K_{3,3}$ so special.

*Edit:* Corrected the statement of the characterisation $K_5$ and $K_{3,3}$.

Comment: It seems to me that the [cube graph](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/CubicalGraph.html) has this property as well.

Comment: No. Remove an edge and you get two squares that overlap at one edge — which is a graph that is a subdivision of $K_{2,3}$.

Comment: Correct me, but two overlapping squares are [outerplanar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outerplanar_graph), and outerplanar graphs do not contain $K_{2,3}$ as a minor.

Comment: You are right, I'll correct the statement of the theorem. (The original statement in the text does not have this problem.